# generate yaml anchors/references with overrides using pyyaml

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

A thing you can do with human-written YAML is this:

```
foo: &foo_anchor
  key1: v1
  key2: v2
  key3: v3
bar:
  <<: *foo_anchor
  key2: override_value
```

I would like to programmatically generate output like that using PyYAML. It seems tricky! By default, as far as I can tell, PyYAML only generates anchors/references when it encounters equal objects (and the order is probably not defined, whereas in this example, `bar` has to reference `foo`, not the other way around).  I've tried a few things—defining a `YamlReference` class and checking for its tag in an overridden `Dumper.serialize_node` method—but trying to do something like:

```py
        if node.tag.endswith('magic.prefix.YamlReference'):
            alias = node.value[0].value
            self.emit(yaml.events.AliasEvent(alias))
            super(Dumper, self).anchor_node(node.value[1])
            super(Dumper, self).serialize_node(node.value[1], parent, idx)
```

messes up the expected event stream. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do something like this:

```
import yaml

class Merger(object):
  pass

def merger_representer(dumper, data):
  return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:merge', '<<')

yaml.add_representer(Merger, merger_representer)

foo = {'key1': 'v1', 'key2': 'v2', 'key3': 'v3'}

root = {
  'foo': foo,
  'bar': {
     Merger(): foo,
     'key2': 'override_value'
  }
}

print(yaml.dump(root, sort_keys=False))
```

Output is:

```
foo: &id001
  key1: v1
  key2: v2
  key3: v3
bar:
  <<: *id001
  key2: override_value
```

`sort_keys=False` ensures correct order of the keys, it requires Python >= 3.7 and PyYAML >= 5.1 (thanks @tinita). You have no control over the generated anchor name, but this YAML is equivalent to yours.

You need the `Merger` class to force PyYAML to emit `<<` (with a normal string key, it would emit `'<<'` so that it doesn't get confused with a merge key).

Comment: In PyYAML >= 5.1 you can actually use `yaml.dump(..., sort_keys=False)`. this will dump the original order of keys if the python version implements it

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is making a class that holds the appropriate
information about the merge information, and still allows lookup of
`data['bar']['key1']`. Of course you need to properly dump this class with an appropriate representer.

This is what ruamel.yaml (disclaimer I am the
author of that package) does to allow round-tripping of merged maps:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
foo: &foo_anchor
  key1: v1
  key2: v2
  key3: v3
bar:
  <<: *foo_anchor
  key2: override_value
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
foo: &foo_anchor
  key1: v1
  key2: v2
  key3: v3
bar:
  <<: *foo_anchor
  key2: override_value
```

So I suggest you look at the class `CommentedMap` and how this is
handled in `constructor.py` and `representer.py`.

If you can upgrade to `ruamel.yaml` then you can do:

```
cm = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap

data = cm()
data['foo'] = foo = cm(key1='v1', key2='v2', key3='v3')
foo.yaml_set_anchor('foo_anchor')
data['bar'] = bar = cm(key2='override_value')
bar.add_yaml_merge([(0, foo)])
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives something similar to what you expect, starting from scratch:

```
foo: &foo_anchor
  key1: v1
  key2: v2
  key3: v3
bar:
  <<: *foo_anchor
  key2: override_value
```

And of course the following works as expected:

```
print(list(data['bar'].keys()))
print(data['bar']['key3'])
```

to give:

```
['key2', 'key1', 'key3']
v3
```

Comment: I eventually figured out how to do this, by directly manipulating `CommentedMap`. This answer, however, is not helpful, because I don't care about roundtripping: I'm not starting from yaml, I'm programmatically generating it.